# Find paradigm/master/archetype in cluster

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I have a dataset that has been separated into clusters of data elements, all of which are supposed to represent a single entity.  Each data element is comprised of variables such as name, phone number, etc. and have been grouped together because they are thought to represent the same person. I do not have information on how they were clustered, but I do have all available information about each data element.

I would like to find/estimate the most representative data element for each cluster. I am unfamiliar with cluster analysis, but am finding that the identification of the "centroid" or "medoid" comes at the clustering algorithm stage and not after.  Can anyone point me in the direction of how I can estimate the master/archetype/paradigm data element for each cluster after the elements have been clustered? Is there any way to determine which rules are most important for deciding whether an element was included in a cluster AFTER the clustering has occurred. Any and all advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Beware that such an object may not be very good., depending on your data. If someoke gave you the cluster {"Apple","apple","banana","Banana"}, which object would you choose?

Three popular choices:

- the **mode**, the most frequent.
- the **medoid**, the object with the *smallest average distance* to the others
- the **minimax**, the object with the *smallest maximum distance* to the others

Foe the mode, you need quantity information. I.e. if you have 10 times "apple" and two times "aple", you would choose the more frequent.

For the other two, you need a very *reliable* distance function (or similarity function). This will be very hard to do if your attributes are of different types. But if we had only a single string with spelling errors, "apple", "appel", "aple", "aaple" then the correct spelling will likely have the smallest distance to the others. But with a badly chosen distance, results will be bad.